# How to reduce the amount of mongodb log

Tags: mongodb, logging

I have changed the loglevel and other settings a bit to receive slow queries.

```
> db.getProfilingStatus()
{ "was" : 1, "slowms" : 10000, "sampleRate" : 1 }
```

```
{
    "was" : {
        "verbosity" : 1,
        "accessControl" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "command" : {
            "verbosity" : 1
        },
        "control" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "executor" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "geo" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "index" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "network" : {
            "verbosity" : 1,
            "asio" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
            },
            "bridge" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
            }
        },
        "query" : {
            "verbosity" : 1
        },
        "replication" : {
            "verbosity" : -1,
            "heartbeats" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
            },
            "rollback" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
            }
        },
        "sharding" : {
            "verbosity" : -1,
            "shardingCatalogRefresh" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
            }
        },
        "storage" : {
            "verbosity" : -1,
            "journal" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
            }
        },
        "write" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "ftdc" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "tracking" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

However, when the log was monitored in real time, the log was being generated at a great speed.

```
2022-02-25T16:32:42.743+0900 I COMMAND  [conn197] command graylog.processing_status command: findAndModify { findAndModify: "processing_status", query: { node_id: "097d696f-fc58-4313-bc6f-447f36719966" }, new: true, upsert: true, update: { node_id: "097d696f-fc58-4313-bc6f-447f36719966", node_lifecycle_status: "RUNNING", updated_at: new Date(1645774362742), receive_times: { ingest: new Date(1645774362424), post_processing: new Date(1645774362424), post_indexing: new Date(1645774361251) }, input_journal: { uncommitted_entries: 6, read_messages_1m_rate: 50.35689976711784, written_messages_1m_rate: 50.35689970907043, journal_enabled: true } }, $db: "graylog" } planSummary: IXSCAN { node_id: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keysInserted:1 keysDeleted:1 numYields:0 reslen:419 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } protocol:op_msg 0ms
```

It is part of the log.
I'm not very good at analyzing mongodb, but I don't think this is a slow query though.

How can I save only slow query and error log to log file? :(

If I change LogLevel to 0, I get no logs...even slow queries.

Comment: Do the [systemlog.component-options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog.component-options) provide the granularity you need?

Comment: To some extent I think so. All I need is a log of slow queries and error levels. Currently I have changed everything to 0 in the above settings.

Comment: I'm still learning so log size isn't important to me yet.  But you got me thinking, if the log can't be quieter, perhaps a well crafted `jq` script could trim it after the log is rotated.

Comment: I need to monitor logs in real time... If it is simply a matter of accumulating a lot, you can just delete it, but I have to extract only the necessary information from this vast amount. Filtering is possible with scripts, but I'm worried about overloading the server.

Comment: Maybe a question on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [MongoDB Developer Community](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/) might get a good answer.